# How to use Directive and Observable to animate dom elements in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, animation, rxjs, angular2-observables

I am trying to animate DOM element in angular5. I am calling manipulateStyle method of my drawingComponent in a loop. it takes x,y co-ordinates as input and renders style on DOM element using directive. 
Same manipulateStyle() method works if called from onInit of drawingComponent i.e. without a loop. but not in loop.
I am using loop because I need to animate for x,y co-ords array.

I have created a **custom directive** taking observable as input, this input observable is subscribed here in ngOnInit() of directive as below

```
@Directive({ selector: '[playerStyle]' })
export class StyleDirective implements OnInit{
  @Input() playerStyle: Observable<any>;
  constructor(public el: ElementRef,public renderer: Renderer) { }
  ngOnInit(){
        this.playerStyle.subscribe(
            result=>
            {
                let style = "transform:"+result.transform+"; position: absolute; 
                top:"+ result.top+ "; left:"+result.left +";";
                this.renderer.setElementProperty(this.el.nativeElement, 'style', 
                style);                
            }     
        );
    }
}
```

drawingcompoenent.ts has a startplaying() function gets invoked by button click

```
StartPlaying(event: any)
    {
        for(let i =0;i<200 ; i+=15)
        {
            this.sleep(100);
            this.manipulateStyle(i,i+5);
        }
    }
```

and a manipulateStyle function

```
   manipulateStyle(top:number,left:number)
   {
        this.styles = { 'transform':'translate(0px,0px)', 'position': 
        'absolute', 'top': top+'px', 'left': left+'px' };
        this.stylechange = new  BehaviorSubject<any>(this.styles);

   }
```

and drawingcompoenent.Html to link with custom directive
this.stylechange is assisgned to directive **[playerStyle] = "stylechange"**

```
 <img src="BallImage.png" [playerStyle] = "stylechange" ngDraggable (stopped)="dragend($event)" (started)="dragstarted($event)">
```

What I'm doing wrong here? Anyone have any suggestion on how to achieve this?

Comment: When you want to animate elements in Angular you should really just use the Angular Animations module instead. It is well documented, well supported and most importantly, extremely powerful. What you want to achieve is just a bunch of declarative lines using the animations module.

Comment: `playerStyle` is already an *Input* property, you don't have to declare it as observable and assign it an observable. Just assign it directly in `manipulateStyle` and in directive, apply styles inside `ngOnChanges`. `console.log` *nativeElement* inside directive after applying styles and see if it applies styles or called at all.

Comment: @abdul-wahab thanks for your response I have tried it inside ngOnchanges it do not animate through all provided co-ords, it just goes straight to last co-ord. Animation effect is missing. Looks like I need to use Angular animations module instead

Comment: @PatrickKelleter looks like you have done similar work in the past, how about greensock and GSAP provided by them for animation?

Comment: So, your styles are applying. Now you need to properly animate them. If you wan to perform animation via JavaScript, you can utilize [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame).

Comment: @sohaibjaved i have never worked with GSAP, but for angular it is highly recommended to use the module shipped with angular itself, since it fits in flawlessly and is based on the Web Animations API, which is the next web standard. polyfills for unsupported browsers are shipped as well.
see here: https://angular.io/guide/animations

Comment: thanks @abdul-wahab requestAnimationFrame fixed it for me, I have used it in angular, not sure its gonna help me all the way. Not sure if at some point I may need to implement Angular animations module instead. Thumbs up for you. It worked. Thanks